# SVG element won't fill the whole container in IE

Tags: image, css, internet-explorer, svg

I use SVG as a background of a div. The CSS styling for the corresponding div are as follow (refer below)

**CSS**

```
#statusheader .status{
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(../img/monitoring.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 230px 250px;
    background-position: center center;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

I have an SVG image with a dimension of 300 x 320 and I scale it with 230 x 250 to fit my needs. Yes it looks good in Chrome but not on Internet Expirer, I mean explorer :D. Like the background width is shrink a little bit which makes the background awful. Any help, clues, ideas, suggestion, recommendation to fix this?

Comment: Check for default paddings and margins, hard to tell without seeing your DOM.

Comment: even I add "margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" it doesnt work, or even I add "!important", it still doesnt work and I'm sure, theres no spaces or padding occupied the div that can cause the background width to shrink. I even added "border: 1px solid red;" to see any spaces but no spaces shown and it just the background image width is shrink

Answer (score 0):

Does the css rule background: cover; work? I'm not too familiar with IE but that works for all my other similar issues.